# Android exception i don't understand after loading webpage in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that loads a webpage. I also have a reload button. Sometimes it works but sometimes it crashes when i hit reload and i get this exceptions:

```
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918): Activity com.poslji.gor.Uvod has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@435da698 that was originally added here
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.poslji.gor.Uvod has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@435da698 that was originally added here
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:217)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:392)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:231)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.poslji.gor.Odgovori$2.onClick(Odgovori.java:120)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6307)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1752)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1206)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1997)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1736)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1752)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1206)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1997)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1736)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1761)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-14 10:08:33.958: ERROR/WindowManager(918):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 10:08:36.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:356)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:201)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:400)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:268)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:69)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:103)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:252)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at com.poslji.gor.Odgovori$HelloWebViewClient.onPageFinished(Odgovori.java:180)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:225)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)


05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-14 10:08:36.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are showing a `ProgressDialog` and not dismissing it, perhaps.